# Setting colors and size inside aes() and inside geom() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a beginner and reading Wickham's `ggplot2` book to understand how this thing works. I am a little confused about setting attributes (color, size etc.) inside and outside `aes()` I have included references I've referred here so far.

I ran XYZ experiments to understand this:

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3), z=c("a","b","c"))
```

**Experiment 1:**

```
 ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) +
   geom_point(size = 4, show.legend = TRUE)
```

This doesn't show the legend although I've set it to TRUE. I am not sure why this is happening.

**Experiment 2:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) +
   geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = z)) #I see the legend
```

This surprisingly shows the legend. I believe that from references, mapping variables to "color" is a valid reason to show the legend. We have mapped a variable to color.

**Experiment 3**

```
ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) +
   geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = z),color = "red")
```

Here, I believe red color is overridden by my second call i.e. color="red". Am I correct?

**Experiment 4:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) +
   geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = z,size=20),color = "red")
```

I wanted to test whether the size increases if I set size = 20 inside aes. It doesn't. I am not sure why because size = 4 was set *before* setting size = 20.

**Experiment 5:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) +
   geom_point(size = 4, color = "red") +
   geom_point(aes(colour = z),size=10) #legend appears, but I have lost border colors.
```

Finally, I thought of keeping `size = 10` outside of aes because I thought setting size = constant inside aes would be defaulting the value of size. This worked in that the size did increase, but I have lost the legend.

I am completely lost -how do I show the legend, increase the size (using variables or manually) or change colors( using variables or manually)? I understand that changing size *and* colors would be the easiest because I would just have to map them to variables. However, I am not sure when I would want to keep one of them (say size or color) constant.

```
 ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) +
   geom_point(aes(colour = z, size = x)) ##this maps color and size to variables.
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts. Finally, I am sorry if my question is too basic for some of you.

---

References: [Difference between passing options in aes() and outside of it in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511911/difference-between-passing-options-in-aes-and-outside-of-it-in-ggplot2)

---

**Update from the thread:** (after discussions for those of us who are reading this...)

**Experiment 1:** No legend shows up because there is no need for one. There is no variable is mapped to size. There's nothing to show in the legend in that case.

**Experiment 2:** There is one layer and it maps to the variable. So, I see the legend.

**Experiment 3:** I have set the color using variable, but then it's overridden by red color.

**Experiment 4** Ditto here. The output of Expt 4 and 3 are the same because of overriding issue.

**Experiment 5** The second layer overlays on top of first layer. One way to reverse this would be:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = z),size=10) +
   geom_point(size = 4, color = "red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read more on **defining aesthetics globally**, and defining them on **local** `geom_xyz()` **layers**.

The thing is, when you define col as attributes, it overrides your aesthetics (`aes()`) mapping. You can see that in your **Experiment 3**.

In the fourth one, you are again overriding the color by mapping it outside of `aes()`.

You should check this link out on aesthetics mapping: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes.html

From the same link:

> ## Aesthetics supplied to ggplot() are used as defaults for every layer
>
> ## you can override them, or supply different aesthetics for each layer

It's nothing so complicated, you should look at the documentation more carefully and it'll come to you naturally.

Comment: Ok. here's what I think is going on: **Experiment 2:**  There is one layer and it maps to the variable. So, I see the legend. **Experiment 3:** I have set the color using variable, but then it's overridden by red color. **Experiment 4** Ditto here. The output of Expt 4 and 3 are the same because of overriding issue. **Experiment 5** The second layer overlays on top of first layer. One way to reverse this would be `ggplot(df, aes(y, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = z),size=10) + geom_point(size = 4, color = "red")` However, I am not sure why legend is not shown in Experiment 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: No legend in experiment 1 because no variables are mapped to colour, fill, size, etc. You've only mapped to x and y (`aes(y,y)` is equivalent to `aes(x=y, y=y)`), which won't produce a legend.

Comment: @ss0208535 In the Experiment 1, you haven't mapped anything inside the global aesthetics, which is why there's no legend. Add 'color = z' inside the aes() of ggplot and you'll see the legend.

Comment: @ss0208535 Did that helped? :)

Comment: @eipi10 I see what's the source of my confusion...Excel would have shown a legend for a `y->y` mapping. I am coming from Excel world, so I get confused sometimes. If I understand you correctly--to show the legend, I would have to map a variable to the aesthetic; setting it (such as `size =2`) to a constant won't be sufficient to produce the legend although it would change the aesthetic. Am I correct?

Comment: @Pj_ Thanks for taking time to help me. That does help me to some extent...

Comment: @ss0208535 To product a legend, you need to map at least some variable to the `aes()`.

Comment: Why would you want a legend for `size` if no variable is mapped to size? There's nothing to show in the legend in that case. If you mean you want to map a variable to color, but also set the size of points, then just do `geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = z))`. This will give you a legend showing what the colors mean, and all the points will have size=4.

Comment: @eipi10 That makes sense. Thanks eipi10. This makes sense. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ss0208535 If the discussion has helped you, can you accept it? It might help others who face issue similar to yours. :)

Comment: @Pj_ Great point. I have updated the question with the discussion with eipi10 and yourself. Thanks so much, for your help...