# Changing color of data points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

First I run this code and it works perfectly (all data points turn blue):

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), color = "blue")
```

But when I try move around the mapping like below, the data points turn black instead of blue.

Why is that?

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), color = "blue") + geom_point()
```

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + geom_point(color = "blue") `

Comment: @G5W's comment is totally right. Just to give you a bit more insight about this; Imagine you also want to connect the points with lines (`geom_line`) and you want the line to be `red`. This is how you implement it: `ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + geom_point(color = "blue") + geom_line(color="red")`. you can use the same mapping (`aes`) for all the `geom`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the variables inside mapping between the geoms. Specifically about `color`, it needs to be defined outside of the `aes` and in the `geom` when setting to a constant (e.g. `"blue"`) and not a variable (explained here: [Answer to: When does the argument go inside or outside aes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864222/6461462)).

I included couple examples below to illustrate this better;

```r
library(ggplot2)
```

```
## works fine for each geom 
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue") + 
  geom_line(color="red")
```

[image]

```r
## doesn't work when not in the geom
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy), color = "blue") + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
## gets evaluated as a variable when in aes
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = "blue"))
```

[image]

```r
## can use a variable in aes, either in geom or ggplot function
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = model), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]