# Fail to set the color and dot size separately when using ggplot with two datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set as shown here:

```
ALL<- structure(list(GI = c(38.448275862069, 40.2659574468085, 85.3378378378378, 
56.4606741573034, 26.5714285714286, 16.8944099378882), GI_D = c(31.5275862068966, 
37.0446808510638, 64.0033783783784, 45.7331460674157, 20.7257142857143, 
14.1913043478261), GI_W = c(34.84375, 39.4270833333333, 83.0921052631579, 
54.6195652173913, 25.5963302752294, 16.4848484848485), NEE_D_mean = c(9.9644036070938, 
-5.49181483024952, -29.5841687938457, -10.950117466455, -9.76133775037159, 
-1.17370950853892), NEE_D_se = c(24.4055666454516, 8.31286897717958, 
43.0803839446216, 42.0054504158082, 28.7765100449838, 8.86774764999355
), NEE_W_mean = c(-10.6866769282934, 20.9456806199394, -24.0380682586804, 
52.3723812566745, -62.2858574112861, 56.3557615426375), NEE_W_se = c(15.2426118086142, 
17.8227858145903, 22.7452815581715, 38.4251278858896, 19.1950340008666, 
25.59062272811), GPP_D_mean = c(2.76586256588453, -14.0740484535984, 
22.0551675189495, 38.2196758481854, -22.2452106112792, 2.92247497333855
), GPP_D_se = c(10.0301104827162, 4.76830515667558, 10.1200654792974, 
13.6220945562145, 12.5521089272372, 4.02070599220442), GPP_W_mean = c(-13.3583364224079, 
5.5457128851295, 6.96224944388818, 30.9347346550519, -24.0637392356731, 
31.1919112040759), GPP_W_se = c(7.79177565854901, 7.68225824264646, 
7.53759987843893, 9.21062180693269, 11.5998936888688, 4.91032534186175
), RE_D_mean = c(-6.92656657644594, -20.2249090077204, -1.55891573291113, 
15.3619823271736, -59.6169736724781, 0.0398744940922411), RE_D_se = c(8.81296607135718, 
3.17951327169943, 7.26103092218914, 9.79375075847273, 33.89046634443, 
3.15632251128507), RE_W_mean = c(-11.2826765406364, -5.50930629197934, 
-7.35527862198859, -3.3802491396303, -5.7039196948544, 15.5927675710877
), RE_W_se = c(7.82782177993256, 3.28089787167971, 5.27000717925753, 
5.7667863399033, 10.1830962186111, 3.17699751136105), site = c("DK_M", 
"DK_B", "UK", "NL", "HU", "IT")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And now I want to make a plot similar to below,
[image]

My code is

```
library(dplyr)

require(ggplot2)
require(ggpmisc)
library(tidyr) 
library(tidyverse) 

target1<- c("UK", "DK_M", "NL","DK_B") #What about "DK_B"?
dat<- filter(ALL, site %in% target1)
fit<- lm(NEE_D_mean~GI,dat)  
summary(fit)  

target2<- c("HU", "DK_M","NL","DK_B")
df<- filter(ALL, site %in% target2)
fit<- lm(RE_D_mean~GI,df)  
summary(fit)  

 
  ggplot(ALL, mapping = aes(x=GI, y=NEE_D_mean))+
  geom_point(aes(x=GI, y=NEE_D_mean,shape=site,color= 'green', size=1))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+ #add a horizontal line= 0
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=NEE_D_mean-NEE_D_se, ymax=NEE_D_mean+NEE_D_se), width=0.5) +
  labs(y='Drought change of NEE from control % ', x= 'Gaussen Index of Aridity', color= ' ')+  #here, note: x and y axis title is reversed.
  geom_smooth (data = dat,aes(x=GI, y=NEE_D_mean),method='lm', formula = y~x,color= 'black', se=FALSE,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  #stat_poly_eq(formula = y~x, eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~", aes(x = 65, y = -20,label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x=GI, y=RE_D_mean,shape= site,color= "blue",size=2))+ #if I add color= "bule" here, it doesn't work at all. why?
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+ #add a horizontal line= 0
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=RE_D_mean-RE_D_se, ymax=RE_D_mean+RE_D_se, color= "blue"), width=0.5, size=1) + #if I add color= "blue" here, it doesn't work at all. why?
  labs(y='Drought change of Reco from control % ', x= 'Gaussen Index of Aridity', color= ' ')+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("NEE"="black", "RE"="green"), drop= F)+   #change the color and match the color with the second legend
  geom_smooth (data = df,aes(x=GI, y=RE_D_mean),method='lm', formula = y~x,color= 'green', se=FALSE,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+
  #theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+ 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.3))+  #change the legend position
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+ #Change the legend title to blank
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  #+annotate(geom="text", x=60, y=10, label="NEE",color="red")
```

The problem is I can't change the size and color of the dots separately. I had set the size of the dots separately, it showed a weird legend on the left. Meanwhile, even if I set the color of the second (RE) graph's dots and error bars to blue, the output color didn't change.

Comment: Only map the aesthetics using `aes()` for variables in your data. Place arguments like `color = "blue"` and `size = 2` outside the `aes()` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864222/6851825

Comment: @caldwellst I tried to put the arguments outside the aes() and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Spring Thanks! It does!