# Scatterplot with color gradient and additional point

Tags: r, ggplot2

After coming back to ggplot2 for some evolve scatterplot, I feel like I am lost:
I have two datasets, `df1` and `df2` (this last being a single point).

```
>df1
    DATE        XOV        DAX
1  16479  2.1880142 -1.8203765
2  16482  2.7930760 -2.1501989
3  16483  2.8998516 -1.9903619
4  16484  1.8676874 -1.8704841
5  16485  1.5473606 -1.8007140
6  16486  1.3338094 -1.4620117
7  16489  0.7643395 -1.4512291
8  16490  0.4084208 -1.2044965
9  16491  0.2660533 -1.2577755
10 16492 -0.5169678 -0.9438099

>df2
   DATE      XOV       DAX
1 13514 1.620395 -1.927569
```

What I wanna obtain **(1)** is a scatterplot with `df1`, with point colored depending on the date, according to a gradient, and **(2)** add the single point in red on it with a bigger size.

I can obtain **(1)** with:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=DAX, y=XOV, colour=DATE)) + 
theme(legend.position="none") + 
scale_colour_gradient(low="#A9C8F3", high="#0C2389")
```

Giving:

[image]

When I wanna add **(2)**, I use:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=DAX, y=XOV, colour=DATE)) + 
theme(legend.position="none") + scale_colour_gradient(low="#A9C8F3", high="#0C2389") + 
geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=DAX, y=XOV, color="red"))
```

But then get the error:

```
$ Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I apologize if it's a duplicate, already looked for solutions but I did not get what was wrong, despite pulling each dataframe out of `ggplot()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the colour argument outside of the aes:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df1, aes(x=DAX, y=XOV, colour=DATE)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low="#A9C8F3", high="#0C2389") +
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=DAX, y=XOV), colour="red",size=5)
```

[image]

Explanation for the behavior can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511911/difference-between-passing-options-in-aes-and-outside-of-it-in-ggplot2):

> When specified inside aes, an aesthetic is mapped to the value of a
>   variable in the data. Since there is a mapping between the data and
>   the visible aesthetic, there is a legend which shows that mapping.
>   Outside of an aes call, the aesthetic is just set to a specific value.

Comment: Dammit. Great for the explanation!

Comment: No problem, I think the explanation is usually more important than the solution ;)